# In a text based RPG, Player object has no attribute loot, how to give it the loot attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Note: I am relatively new to Python and coding. I am creating a text based RPG by following along in a book titled *Make Your Own Python Text Adventure* by *Phillip Johnson*. I have completed the book and now am taking its advice to customize my game and make my own objects and classes.

I am attempting to create a Map Tile called LootTile that allows the player to pick up a loot item called Fancy Chocolate and store it in their inventory automatically. However, I keep getting different errors regarding the loot. The first one, the biggest one that I'm not sure how to fix, is an `AttributeError`.

I know I probably have to create a loot attribute in the Player class, but I'm not sure how. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I'll post my Traceback and the related code here.

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Hall\Desktop\Yradel_Game\Yradel_Game5.py", line 102, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Hall\Desktop\Yradel_Game\Yradel_Game5.py", line 49, in main
    room.modify_player(player)
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Hall\Desktop\Yradel_Game\world.py", line 132, in modify_player
    player.loot = player.loot + self.loot
AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'loot'
```

*player.py*

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = [items.Dagger(), items.BreadRoll(), items.Potion()]
        self.x = world.start_tile_location[0]
        self.y = world.start_tile_location[1]
        self.hp = 100
        self.gold = 100
        self.victory = False
        # self.loot = ?
```

*world.py*

```
class LootTile(MapTile):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.loot = items.FancyChocolate
        self.loot_claimed = False

    def modify_player(self, player):
        if not self.loot_claimed:
            self.loot_claimed = True
            player.loot = player.loot + self.loot
            print("You've retrieved a Fancy Chocolate!")
    def intro_text(self):
        if self.loot_claimed:
            return """The underbrush looks the same here, time to move on!"""
        else:
            return """There is a tree stump with a yummy looking piece of chocolate on it."""
```

Comment: `self.loot = 0` assuming its an integer and starts at 0?

Comment: That gives me a `TypeError`
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Hall\Desktop\Yradel_Game\Yradel_Game5.py", line 102, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Hall\Desktop\Yradel_Game\Yradel_Game5.py", line 49, in main
    room.modify_player(player)
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Hall\Desktop\Yradel_Game\world.py", line 132, in modify_player
    player.loot = player.loot + self.loot
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'type'`

Comment: Oh i see, it should be `self.loot = []` because its a list of items. And the corresponding tile logic is `player.append(self.loot)`

Comment: It still answered the original question, how do you assign a value to the attribute. Getting a different error is progress.

Comment: We're making progress. Now it's saying `'Player' object has no attribute 'append'`

Answer (score 0):

im from argentina so my games "front end" is all in spanish, but i achieved a similar thing to what you're trying by going about it like this:

```
class ItemTile(MapTile):
    def __init__(self, x, y, item):
        self.item = item
        self.item_claimed = False
        super().__init__(x, y)
 
    def add_loot(self, player):
        player.inventory.append(self.item)
 
    def modify_player(self, player):
        if not self.item_claimed:
            self.item_claimed = True
            self.add_loot(player)
        
class ChoriRoom(ItemTile):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y, items.ChoriPan())
 
    def intro_text(self):
        if self.item_claimed:
            return """
            aca no hay nada
            """
        else:
            return """
        Te encontras un choripan calentito sobre una mesa abandonada
        en un restobar.
        """

class BirraRoom(ItemTile):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y, items.Birra())
 
    def intro_text(self):
        if self.item_claimed:
            return """
            aca no hay nada
            """
        else:
            return """
        Te encontras una birra tibia en el marco de una ventana
        Medio un asco, pero anda a saber cuando vas a conseguir una fría.
        """
```

i dont really know how to explain it very well in english, but i believe its pretty self explainatory, one parent itemtile class, and then a child class for every "lootable item" to be picked up every time you walk for the first time into any "child" tile of the "parent" itemtile.